# Many big issues in the website, WP_Debug not showing

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, advanced-custom-fields, plugin-wpml, wp-debug

I have this website https://itds.pl/ suddenly it started working really bad and I can't find the reason.

Website is Multi website system
Using WPML
Using ACF
Have two domains:

1. Main domain Eng and has Polish path
2. Second Domain Portuguese and has Eng path

Issues that we have:

1. Once you logged in as and admin and try to see the main domain the pages are white, but the menu is working (screenshot 1) [image]
2. The PL path stopped working at all, the blank page https://itds.pl/pl/
3. Portuguese version is showing even when you logged in as an admin but on the About Us page there is half of the page not showing [image], but on main domain it looks good.

The main problem that I don't understand is why I can't see an error, I turned on WP_debug but still have nothing to see. I also tried to follow some advice about the error logs, and tried to make it through the .htaccess but still empty

What I have done so far:

1. Turned on debug mode - result - 0 - issues not showing at all
2. Turned on the cache plugin, and then defense plugin - nothing, still the same problem
3. Checked the code on the About Us page - nothing outdated, nothing changed
4. Checked the WPML Support page on the website that checks the system, and noticed that the memory limit is too low
5. Increased memory limit from 64 to 256 in the config file - nothing
6. Updated plugins - nothing
7. Updated WP core - nothing

Have anyone had something similar? Could you please help me to see an error? Maybe there are any other ways? We don't have access to the server or to the Google tag manager since we see also issues there [image] So would like to know if there is a way to find out an issue from admin side? Though we have access to the FTP

Comment: did you update WP recently without updating WPML?

Comment: Yes, but this issues was before updating, but then I rolled back everything and updated WPML and then the Core :/